# How to un-add file from last commit but keep local changes?

Tags: git

I edited two files. I wanted to commit both files separately. I accidentally did:

```
git add file_one
git commit -am 'Change something in file_one'
```

The `-a` flag committed my changes to `file_two` as well, which I didn't want.

How do I undo that?

What I was aiming for from the start was:

```
git add file_one
git commit -m 'Change something in file_one'
git add file_two
git commit -m 'Change file_two'
```

---

I tried

```
git reset --soft HEAD^ -- file_two
```

but soft reset doesn't work with paths apparently, and I also tried (rip)

```
git checkout HEAD~ -- file_two
git commit --amend
```

but now I just completely deleted all changes in file_two.... annoyingly. I'm asking the question so I don't make such a mistake again.

Comment: It's easy. `git reset HEAD~1; git commit -s -c ORIG_HEAD -- path/to/file_with_the_original_commit_message; git commit -a -s # the rest`. Here I have script which commits one file per commit: https://github.com/andy-shev/home-bin-tools/blob/master/gc4name.sh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT: I initially misunderstood the question so this answer intially suggested deleting `file_2` from the staging tree. As Enrico pointed out in the comments, that isn't what you want if `file_2` isn't new.**

You can restore the staged version of `file_2` to its pre-commit state with:

```
git reset HEAD^ -- file_two
```

You want a mixed reset because you want to affect the staging tree.

Then you can amend your last commit with:

```
git commit --amend
```

Your working tree will be unaffected.

Answer (score 2):

### Edit

This answer was posted before [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60347178/5825294) was fixed. At the moment I think that one is better than mine, technically speaking.

### Original answer

The OP had a repo going on very well

```
mkdir testdir
cd testdir/
git init
echo 'historical content of file_one' > file_one
echo 'historical content of file_two' > file_two
git add file_one file_two
git commit -m 'this is the most recent commit the OP is happy with'
```

Then the OP started editing both files, with the intention of committing them in two separate commits,

```
echo 'one more line to file_one' >> file_one
echo 'one more line to file_two' >> file_two
```

however the OP made a mistake, commmitting both files:

```
git commit -am 'this commit was meant to be only for file_one'
```

At this point, I would do the following:

```
git reset HEAD~
```

which essentially goes back to before `git add file_one file_two`, and then I'd stage `file_one` and commit it using the old message, and then stage `file_two` and commit it too:

```
git add file_one
git commit --reuse-message=HEAD@{1}
git add file_two
git commit -m 'Committing only changes to file_two
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just undo last commit and then you can commit both files separately in 2 different commits. You needed to just soft/hard reset to remove the entire last commit from git
hard reset - `git reset --hard HEAD^` - doesn't preserve the undone changes
soft reset - `git reset --soft HEAD^` - does preserves the undone changes locally